# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration during Jersey initialization after upgrading WebLogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic12c

I am using Apache CXF for my webservices implementation and Weblogic as application server. My application was running fine on Weblogic version 12.1.3 . Recently I upgraded my Weblogic version to 12.2.1.3 . After the upgrade when I am starting my application I am getting Jersey related errors. I am not even using Jersey in my application. Below is the complete stack trace of error:

```
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet$ApplicationImpl because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192511> <The list of resource packages: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider;com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json;com.landisgyr.components.server.webservices.cxf.base;org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation;org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.nio;org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.cache>

<Warning> <org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors> <BEA-000000> <The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractResponseViewProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.

<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "JAX-RS/Jersey#1" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myapplication".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/Configuration
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1733471061322200" for task "2" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

<Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:72)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:797)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:465)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2064)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2041)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1930)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @JoeyAbano Yes I resolved the issue by removing the jersey related jars from the weblogic lib. This was the only option worked for me.